# I am getting a command not found error in my bash script

Tags: bash

This script I'm writing looks through a directory and counts the number of regular files and directories respectively. My code is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#countf.sh
#this file counts the number of files and directories in a path recursively
#Variables
declare -i filecount="0"
declare -i dircount="0"
for file in /*
do
if [ -f $file ]
then
$((filecount++))
elif [ -d $file ]
then
$((dircount++))
fi
done
echo The number of files is "$filecount"
echo The number of directories is "$dircount"
echo $?
```

The output I get is:

```
./countf.sh: line 14: 0: command not found
./countf.sh: line 14: 1: command not found
./countf.sh: line 14: 2: command not found
./countf.sh: line 14: 3: command not found
./countf.sh: line 14: 4: command not found
./countf.sh: line 14: 5: command not found
./countf.sh: line 11: 0: command not found
./countf.sh: line 11: 1: command not found
./countf.sh: line 14: 6: command not found
./countf.sh: line 14: 7: command not found
./countf.sh: line 14: 8: command not found
./countf.sh: line 14: 9: command not found
./countf.sh: line 14: 10: command not found
./countf.sh: line 14: 11: command not found
./countf.sh: line 14: 12: command not found
./countf.sh: line 14: 13: command not found
./countf.sh: line 14: 14: command not found
./countf.sh: line 14: 15: command not found
./countf.sh: line 14: 16: command not found
./countf.sh: line 14: 17: command not found
./countf.sh: line 14: 18: command not found
./countf.sh: line 14: 19: command not found
./countf.sh: line 14: 20: command not found
./countf.sh: line 14: 21: command not found
./countf.sh: line 11: 2: command not found
./countf.sh: line 11: 3: command not found
The number of files is 4
The number of directories is 22
0
```

The script appears to be working fine minus the command not found error code that appears after filecount or dircount is incremented.

Comment: Better indent your code when you need help or show your code to anyone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the line 14, replace

```
$((dircount++))
```

by

```
((dircount++))
```

Check http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr